# Inject Context object to create FirebaseAnalytic instance | Mockito

Tags: android, google-analytics, mockito, android-context, firebase-analytics

I'm writting test case for Firebase Analytics(FBA) event wrote in application. In one of case I need to check if FBA object is available or not. I'm following this to create context using Mockito:

**First Approach**

```
   @Mock lateinit var mockContext: Context

    @Test
    fun validateAnalyticsObjectAvailableSuccess() {
        Analytics.with(context)
    }
```

This is **with** call that simply pass context and initialise FBA object:

```
fun with(context: Context) {
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context)
    }
```

But I'm getting following error log with Null pointer exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
>
> at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq.checkNotNull(Unknown
> Source)   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzchj.zzdu(Unknown Source)
> at
> com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(Unknown
> Source)

In **second approach** I'm creating context object this way:

```
lateinit var context: Context

    @Before @Override
    fun setUp() {
        context = Mockito.mock(Context::class.java)
        Mockito.`when`(context.applicationContext).thenReturn(context)
    }
```

and then using this context object with **Analytics.with(context)** but it's same result. Any suggestion if this is not the behaviour of generated context object ?

**Please note**, in both case context object is not null but as soon I uses it for other purpose e.g. context.resource it return null.

Comment: Is this question still actual?

Comment: were you able to get any solution?